# How to create a new blank array within a function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that extracts a column of data from a parent array, but I don't know how to make the function create a new blank array for this data to be stored in.

The function has two variables "title" and "column", where "title" would be the desired name of the new array for the extracted data (currently I just input the name of a pre-defined array), and "column" defines which column in the parent array is to be extracted.

I should also state I'm using a Jupyter notebook.

Here's the code:

```
def extract_col(title, column):
    title = [data[:,column]]
```

Where "data" in the code is just the name of the parent array.  Here's an example:

```
extract_col(array1, 3)
```

This input should create an array called array1, which consists of column 3 of the parent  array, "data".

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should give a complete (but minimal) example, including how you create `data`. Do you use NumPy? If so, please state this and perhaps add "numpy" as a tag.

Comment: @jmd_dk Hi, I am indeed using numpy, and have updated the question to provide a bit more clarity.

Comment: Why do you need to do this.  Isn't `b = a[:, column]` good enough, where `b` is the name of the new array?  Why does this need to be a function?  Or create a name from a string?  That's not recommended Python coding style.  Sometimes it's useful to put items in a `dict`, such as `d[title] = a[:, column]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Basically because it means that currently in my notebook I have this:  
`MI_Z2 = np.array(data[:,0]) 
BAL_FLAG = np.array(data[:,1])  
FIRST_FR_TYPE = np.array(data[:,2])  
R_6CM_2500A = np.array(data[:,3])  
LOGL3000 = np.array(data[:,4])  
LOGL5100 = np.array(data[:,5])  
FWHM_MGII = np.array(data[:,6])  
redshift = np.array(data[:,7])  
mag_g = np.array(data[:,8])`  
Where I was hoping to just be able to call the function the first time I needed each specific data set (remember it's not one file that's all executed at the same time: in Jupyter you execute cell by cell)

Comment: `MI_Z2, BAL_FLAG, FIRST_FR_TYPE = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]` would be a more compact way.

Comment: @hpaulj Don't know why I didn't think of this, looks much nicer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the goal using this (this creates a variable like you are wanting):

```
def extract_col(title, column):
    locals()[title] = data[:,column]
```

However you should not use `locals()` to make a new variable for this (or ever). Instead use a dictionary, not a variable:

```
def extract_col(title, column):
    d = {}
    d[title] = data[:,column]
```

Then you can just call d[title] where you need it.

If you are using `np.array()` and want a new empty array as you mention in the question you can use:

```
def extract_col(title, column):
    d = {}
    d[title] = np.array([])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get an error for whatever I use  as "title" being undefined when I use this method.

Comment: @LiamPaterson are you sending the title as a string?

Comment: You must send title as a string for this to work

Comment: @LiamPaterson for example you need to use this call: `extract_col('array1', 3)` where array1 is a string. You will also most likely want to `return d` or something so you can use the variable later.